# instant search dome how to apply OR in typesense

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-instantsearch, typesense

i have following menu in my dashboard page
[main menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KNfUx.png)

and each main menu has some sub menus
like [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6k3xh.png)
when i click multiple main menu and sub menu type sense generate query like this to get results in api call
filter_by: "cryptoScoreCoarse:=[`Unacceptable`,`Caution`] && cryptoScore:=[`Broken`]"
now i want to make it use OR operator instead of &&,but i dont how can i do this? any idea or suggestion? thanks in advance,here is the screen shot of network tab when api call made
[network tab sceenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/88L1C.png)

Comment: Are you asking what the javascript logical OR operator is?  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_OR

Comment: thanks james,no  asking about  how to generate  typesense query like 
filter_by: "cryptoScoreCoarse:=[Unacceptable,Caution] OR cryptoScore:=[Broken]"
with instant search

Comment: from [filter_by docs](https://typesense.org/docs/0.22.2/api/documents.html#search-parameters) To do ORs across different fields ..., you want to split each condition into separate queries in a multi-query request and then aggregate the text match scores across requests.

Comment: yeah i know it, but i am using connectRefinmentList from react-instant-search-dom, and i only have refine method ,manually i can but i am not allowed to do it

Comment: You might want to add that info, and your related code, to the question.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the `operator` prop for the `RefinementList` widget to change the `OR` to an `AND` as described [here](https://www.algolia.com/doc/api-reference/widgets/refinement-list/react/#widget-param-operator).

```
<RefinementList
  // ...
  operator="and"
/>
```